# Handling Imbalance Categorical Value in A Dataframe Column

Tags: r, python, categorical-data, pandas

I have a dataframe contains id, gender, and class, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8',9,10],
                    'gender': ['Male','Female','Male','Female','Male','Male','Male','Female','Male','Male'],
                    'class': [1,1,3,1,2,3,2,1,3,3]}
                    )
```

I try to make fair comparison about which class student prefer based on their gender but as you can see there is imbalance value in gender. How I can handle this problem?

Comment: Take the classes by the gender instead of the entire column.

Comment: What kind of students are these? College students? High-school students? Did they actually have a choice which class to take?

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing?

Comment: What do you mean by imbalance value? It seems to me there are no missing values in your data. You can for instance run cross-tabulation of gender and class and conduct a chi-square test to find out whether men or women are more likely to be in one of the classes.